# Getting facebook likes per comment without making separate calls per comment id.

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When I get a facebook page comments list:

```
nike/posts?fields=comments
```

For each comment I only get the following fields:

```
         "created_time": "",
            "from": {
              "name": "",
              "id": ""
            },
            "message": "",
            "id": "10155265827713445_10155266595898445"
```

Is there a way to also request the summary of likes/reactions counts for each comment? The only way I was to take the id, and do another call per comment, which is kinda crazy (and slow):

```
10155265827713445_10155266595898445?fields=reactions.limit(0).summary(true)
```

And then I take it from:

```
 "reactions": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0,
      "viewer_reaction": "NONE"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Field Expansion syntax for this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

```
nike/posts?fields=comments{reactions.limit(0).summary(true)}
```

If you need other fields of the comments object as well, you need to ask for them by adding them to the list, comma separated.

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find it in the docs. Where is it specified in the docs? Also - can I get how many comment replies there are somehow?

Comment: It’s specified in the chapter on basic API usage - the section I linked to ;-)

Comment: You can request a summary for comments, too - but it is not that easy to get into the above syntax. Basically you need `comments.summary(1).limit(0)` - but requesting the reactions at the same time using above syntax is tricky. I would suggest to make use of [Field Aliases](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields) here, and request the comments field twice, once to get the reactions, and once to get the summary of the comments, as differently named fields in the result.

Comment: That would look something like this then, `nike/posts?fields=comments{reactions.limit(0).summary(true)},comments.summary(1).limit(0).as(numcomments)` You will see a new property named `numcomments` in the resulting data structure, that contains the count of comments for the post.

Comment: Your ending "}" wasn't in the right place, but even when I moved it `nike/posts?fields=comments{reactions.limit(0).summary(true),comments.summary(1)‌​.limit(0).as(numcomm‌​ents)}` this syntax still didn't work out.

Comment: Oh figured it out. You just switched the order of limit and summary, this works: `nike/posts?fields=comments{reactions.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true).as(numofcomments)}` THANKS!

Comment: btw I don't think I actually need the ".as" is that usually used to avoid name clash?

Comment: Yes, because in my version I was requesting the `comments` field twice, that would throw an error otherwise. Not sure if your version is actually correct now, because with (essentially) `comments{comments}` as you have it now, I think you are counting _reply comments_ made on a top level comment.